# How to loop through AEM multifield component when each field has multiple values

Tags: javascript, html, aem

I've created a custom multifield component (titled "breadcrumbs") that will be used as a page's breadcrumbs nav. Each multifield item consists of a textfield and a pathbrowser. I want to list out each multifield item as an anchor tag with the "text" property as the text and the "link" property as the href.

right now, i just have my html listing out the properties as follows:

```
<div>
    <p>${properties.text}</p>
    <p>${properties.link}</p>
</div>
```

which outputs this to the page:

```
text 1,text 2

link 1,link 2
```

I know how to use data-sly-list and data-sly-repeat for each of the properties to get a list of all the texts and links like this:

```
<ul data-sly-list="${properties.text}">
    <li><p>${items}</p></li>
</ul>

<ul data-sly-list="${properties.link}">
    <li><p>${items}</p></li>
</ul>
```

but is there a way to list out both properties into one element that would look something like this:

```
<ul data-sly-repeat.breadcrumbs="${properties}">
    <li>
        <a href="${breadcrumbs.text}">
            ${breadcrumbs.link}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have also tried data-sly-use with a custom js file, but also can't get multiple properties to loop in one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd strongly recommend going with a multifield that stores the fields as JSON or nodes like ACS multifield so you get a better data structure for your purpose. I do not recommend the below solution unless you are 100% certain that both `link` and `text` are going to be the same length AND in the correct order.

that said, assuming text and link are each multivalued properties, here is what you can do:

```
<ul data-sly-list.textItem="${properties.text}">
    <li>
        <a data-sly-attribute.href="${properties.link[textItemList.index]}">
            ${textItem}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

this will print:

```
ul>
    <li>
        <a title-href="link1">

        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a title-href="link2">

        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

since the var name for `data-sly-list`, the custom identifier `textItemList` is created. We are interested in the member `index` on `textItemList` and use that to display the item at the same index in `link` by doing: `properties.link[textItemList.index]`

read more about [`data-sly-list` in the spec](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#226-list)

*note: you can also do this with the `data-sly-repeat`

Comment: thank you! this solution works, but i will look into ACS multifield too. What is the significance of using "data-sly-attribute.title.href"? this does list out the property correctly, but i need a regular "href" attribute as well. when i just use 

     href="${properties.link[textItemList.index]}"

it doesnt show anything...

Comment: I edited my answer to use: `data-sly-attribute.href` I had an error with it before. should work now. This will output `href="link1"` for example.

Comment: what error were you getting? I'm not getting an error, it just shows an anchor tag but with no attributes. everything else seems to be working fine

Comment: I didn’t get an error, it was incorrect/unnecessary addition of .title

Comment: got it now! plain "href" didn't work, but it was due to a caching issue. Also using "${item}" in the anchor tag didn't work, so I had to change it to "${textItem}" fyi

Comment: yes, it had to be `textItem`, updated. I did my testing of [HTL repl](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-htl-repl) then changed it to match your code :)